# XML to python using beautifulsoup and different XML types

Tags: python, sql, xml, beautifulsoup, mysql-python

I'm working with some xml and my job now is to get the xml and get some data to SQL db..

The thing is, I have to types of xml docs like:

I have "cpc-definition-A.xml":

```
<definition-item><classification-symbol scheme="cpc">A46B3/04</classification-symbol><definition-title>by mouldable materials, e.g. metals, cellulose derivatives, plastics (<class-ref scheme="cpc">A46B1/00</class-ref> takes precedence)</definition-title><limiting-references>
         <section-title>References relevant to classification in this group</section-title>
         <section-body>
            <table>
               <table-row>
                  <table-column preferred-width="9.29cm">
                     <paragraph-text type="body">Bristles and carrier or body moulded in one piece</paragraph-text>
                  </table-column>
                  <table-column preferred-width="5.74cm">
                     <paragraph-text type="body"> <class-ref scheme="cpc">A46B1/00</class-ref> </paragraph-text>
                  </table-column>
               </table-row>
            </table>
         </section-body>
      </limiting-references></definition-item>
```

and "cpc-scheme-A.xml":

```
<classification-item breakdown-code="false" not-allocatable="false" level="8" additional-only="false" sort-key="A46B3/04" definition-exists="true" ipc-concordant="A46B3/04" date-revised="2013-01-01" status="published"><classification-symbol>A46B3/04</classification-symbol><class-title date-revised="2013-01-01"><title-part><text scheme="ipc">by mouldable materials, e.g. metals, cellulose derivatives, plastics </text><reference><text scheme="ipc"><class-ref scheme="cpc">A46B1/00</class-ref> takes precedence</text></reference></title-part></class-title></classification-item>
```

exactly like that on the files(have thousands of each on each file)

some info has in one, but some doesn't, and I'd like to know why there has to be the 2 files to get the full info...
It's my first time working with XML and I can't find this anywhere..

To parse it with python to SQL I'll use BeautifulSoup from bs4 and MySQLdb, it's the best idea or does anyone has a better one?

anyway, I know that is really noob questions, but I really need to solve it..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the XML schema as the metadata; it provides information about the xml document that is both human-readable and machine-processable (next to other things). More info on xml schemas [here](https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/schema).

You can definitely use BeautifulSoup to parse XML files & MySQLdb for db interaction if that is what you want to do :)

Comment: thanks! but why in schema, for example, have some <classification-item> tags that does not have a </classification-item> ? does the bs4 recognize that?

Comment: Do you mean that the tags aren't properly closed?

Comment: I haven't used bs4, but I guess it would throw an error if the tags aren't closed. 
To handle this, you can add the tag manually to the file/string whenever this is the case. Of course, only do this when you're sure you want to ..

Comment: (answered as a new answer)

Comment: You can read it line by line and if bs4 can't process it, try adding the </classification-item> and try to parse the line again.

Or, you could not use bs4 and search for level in the line.

Answer (score 0):

answering here because of the code

for instance, I have this:

for instance, I have this:

```
'<classification-item breakdown-code="false" not-allocatable="false" level="9" additional-only="false" sort-key="A42B1/06" definition-exists="false" ipc-concordant="A42B1/06" date-revised="2013-01-01" status="published"><classification-symbol>A42B1/06</classification-symbol><class-title date-revised="2013-01-01"><title-part><text scheme="ipc">Caps with flaps</text></title-part><title-part><text scheme="ipc">Motoring caps</text></title-part><title-part><text scheme="ipc">Caps with means for protecting the eyes, ears, or nape of neck </text><reference><text scheme="ipc">ear and nape protecting devices in general <class-ref scheme="cpc">A41D</class-ref></text></reference></title-part><title-part><text scheme="ipc">Caps with airpads or removable linings</text></title-part></class-title>
<classification-item breakdown-code="false" not-allocatable="false" level="10" additional-only="false" sort-key="A42B1/061" definition-exists="false" ipc-concordant="A42B1/06" date-revised="2013-01-01" status="published"><classification-symbol>A42B1/061</classification-symbol><class-title date-revised="2013-01-01"><title-part><CPC-specific-text><text scheme="cpc">Caps or soft head coverings with means for protecting the eyes; Uniform caps</text></CPC-specific-text></title-part></class-title>
<classification-item breakdown-code="false" not-allocatable="false" level="11" additional-only="false" sort-key="A42B1/062" definition-exists="true" ipc-concordant="A42B1/06" date-revised="2013-01-01" status="published"><classification-symbol>A42B1/062</classification-symbol><class-title date-revised="2013-01-01"><title-part><CPC-specific-text><text scheme="cpc">Peaks; Visors</text></CPC-specific-text></title-part></class-title>
<classification-item breakdown-code="false" not-allocatable="false" level="12" additional-only="false" sort-key="A42B1/063" definition-exists="false" ipc-concordant="A42B1/06" date-revised="2013-01-01" status="published"><classification-symbol>A42B1/063</classification-symbol><class-title date-revised="2013-01-01"><title-part><CPC-specific-text><text scheme="cpc">with stiffening means</text></CPC-specific-text></title-part></class-title></classification-item>'
```

I need to get the 4 levels of it, but it has 4  and 1

this repeat a lot in the schema, and level it's only on it..